# MKMapView Off Screen Annotation Image Incorrect

Tags: iphone, ios6, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a map to which I add several annotations, like so:

```
    for (Users *user in mapUsers){

        double userlat = [user.llat doubleValue];
        double userLong = [user.llong doubleValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoord = {.latitude =  userlat, .longitude =  userLong};

        MapAnnotationViewController *addAnnotation = [[MapAnnotationViewController alloc] initWithCoordinate:userCoord];

        NSString *userName = user.username;
        NSString *relationship = user.relationship;

        [addAnnotation setTitle:userName];
        [addAnnotation setRelationshipParam:relationship];

        [self.mainMapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    }
```

Using this delegate method code:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapAnnotationViewController class]]) {

    MKAnnotationView *annView = (MKAnnotationView *)[self.mainMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!annView) {
        annView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                          reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    MapAnnotationViewController *sac = (MapAnnotationViewController *)annView.annotation;

    if ([sac.relationshipParam isEqualToString:@"paramA"])
    {
        annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
    }
    else if ([sac.relationshipParam isEqualToString:@"paramB"])
    {
        annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
    }
    else if ([sac.relationshipParam isEqualToString:@"paramC"])
    {
        annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];
    }


    return annView;
}
else {
    return nil;
}
```

This all works fine on the original loading of the map. However, when I select the annotation (which has custom code that is too long to post but includes a zoom in) the annotation images that were previously drawn have changed icons. The map is not redrawn and the annotations are not re-added in that process. When I pinch back out on the map, the images are different (they have match the incorrect relationship params with the wrong image1-3.png's.

Can anyone think of why this is happening, or what to look for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` may return an annotation view that was used for an annotation different from the current `annotation` parameter.

If the `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` is succesful (ie. you're using a previously-used annotation view), you must update its `annotation` property to be sure the view matches the current `annotation`'s properties.

So try changing this part:

```
MKAnnotationView *annView = (MKAnnotationView *)[self.mainMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (!annView) {
    annView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                      reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
MapAnnotationViewController *sac = (MapAnnotationViewController *)annView.annotation;
```

to:

```
MKAnnotationView *annView = (MKAnnotationView *)[self.mainMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (!annView) {
    annView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                      reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
else {
    annView.annotation = annotation; // <-- add this
}

MapAnnotationViewController *sac = (MapAnnotationViewController *)annView.annotation;
```

Another potential issue (not causing the problem in the question) is that the view's `image` property is only set if `relationshipParam` is one of three values.

If somehow `relationshipParam` is not one of those three coded values *and* the view was dequeued, the image will be based on some other annotation's `relationshipParam`.

So you should add an `else` part to the section that sets `image` and set it to some default image just in case:

```
...
else if ([sac.relationshipParam isEqualToString:@"paramC"])
{
    annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];
}
else
{
    annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UnknownRelationship.png"];
}
```

Comment: Great answer ANNA helping me even after a long time