# Click on map pin gives wrong info

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

The problem I have is that when I click on the pin, it gives the wrong info associated with that same pin. I think the index of the pin may not be the same has the index of the array.

Here is the code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;

    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil )
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                       initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

        if ((annotation.coordinate.latitude == mapLatitude) && (annotation.coordinate.longitude == mapLongitude)) {

                if ([estadoUser isEqualToString:@"online"])
                    {
                       // NSLog(@"ONLINE");
                        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1352472516_speech_bubble_green.png"];    //as suggested by Squatch
                    }else{
                        //NSLog(@"OFFLINE");
                        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1352472468_speech_bubble_red.png"]; 
                    }
        }
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(showDetails)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    } else {
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
        }
    return pinView;
}

-(void)showDetails
{
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    DMChatRoomViewController *_controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DmChat"];
    [self presentViewController:_controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[DisplayMap class]])
    {   
         NSInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation]      

        DisplayMap *annotation = (DisplayMap *)view.annotation;

        NSMutableDictionary *item = [allMapUsers objectAtIndex:index];

    //HERE DOES NOT DISPLAY THE INFO ON THE CORRECT PLACE

        NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:[[allMapUsers objectAtIndex:index] objectId] forKey:@"userSelecionadoParaChat"];


        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }  
}

-(void)reloadMap
{
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    for (int i=0; i<allMapUsers.count; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *item = [allMapUsers objectAtIndex:i];

        NSLog(@"index=%i  para objectID=%@",i,[[allMapUsers objectAtIndex:i] objectId]);

        if (([[item valueForKey:@"estado"] isEqualToString:@"offline"] && [[defaults stringForKey:@"showOfflineUsers"] isEqualToString:@"no"]) || [[item valueForKey:@"estado"] isEqualToString:@""]) {

        }else{

        estadoUser = [item valueForKey:@"estado"];

        [outletMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [outletMapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [outletMapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

        MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
        region.center.latitude = [[item valueForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue];

        region.center.longitude = [[item valueForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];

        region.span.longitudeDelta = 81;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 80;
        [outletMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
        /////
        mapLatitude = [[item valueForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue];
        mapLongitude = [[item valueForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D locationco = {mapLatitude,mapLongitude};

        ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
        ann.coordinate = locationco;


        ann.title =   [item valueForKey:@"username1"];
            NSLog(@"ann.title=%@  para objectID=%@",[item valueForKey:@"username1"],[[allMapUsers objectAtIndex:i] objectId]);
        ann.subtitle = [item valueForKey:@"estado"];
        ann.coordinate = region.center;
        [outletMapView addAnnotation:ann];

        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english and if you dont understand the question please dont downrate, just ask, im always around to answer.

Best Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `didSelectAnnotationView`, this code:

```
NSInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation]      
DisplayMap *annotation = (DisplayMap *)view.annotation;
NSMutableDictionary *item = [allMapUsers objectAtIndex:index];
```

won't always work because the map view's `annotations` array is in ***no way guaranteed*** to have the annotations in the same order that you added them.  (See [MKMapView annotations changing/losing order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539802/mkmapview-annotations-changing-losing-order) and [How to reorder MKMapView annotations array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017305/how-to-reorder-mkmapview-annotations-array) for details on this point.)

You ***cannot assume at all*** that the `index` of the annotation in the `mapView.annotations` array is the same index of the annotation's source data in your `allMapUsers` array.

What you can do instead is keep a reference to the source object in the annotation itself.

For example, add an `NSMutableDictionary` property to your `DisplayMap` class:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *sourceDictionary;
```

When creating the annotation, set the property:

```
ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
ann.sourceDictionary = item;  // <-- keep ref to source item
ann.coordinate = locationco;
```

Then in `didSelectAnnotationView`:

```
DisplayMap *annotation = (DisplayMap *)view.annotation;
NSMutableDictionary *item = annotation.sourceDictionary;
```

Another possible problem is here in `viewForAnnotation`:

```
pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotation...
if ( pinView == nil )
    pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] ...
pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
```

If the dequeue returns a previously-used view, it's `annotation` property will still be pointing to the annotation it was previously used for.  When using a dequeued view, you must update its `annotation` property to the current annotation:

```
pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotation...
if ( pinView == nil )
    pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] ...
else
    pinView.annotation = annotation;  // <-- add this
pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
```

See [MKMapView Off Screen Annotation Image Incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869635/mkmapview-off-screen-annotation-image-incorrect/13870025#13870025) for more details.

Comment: And that's why you're on 24.8k. V. through answer.