# map with photos like Instagram Photo Map

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm trying to create a Map with photos kind of like Instagrams Photo Map.

Photo Map: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0wDa.jpg

How can I get the Image (loaded from Parse), to the annotation, like in the screenshot above?

And this is what I got so far:
MapViewController.m

```
[PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"HomePopulation"];
        [query whereKey:@"geopoint" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinKilometers:3000];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                     PFGeoPoint *thePoint = [object objectForKey:@"geopoint"];
                    latitude = thePoint.latitude;
                    longitude = thePoint.longitude;

                    NSLog(@" Hej %f, %f", latitude, longitude);
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

                    Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
                    annotation.coordinate = annotationCoordinate;
                    annotation.title = [object objectForKey:@"discovery"];
                    annotation.subtitle = [object objectForKey:@"location"];

                    PFFile *image = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
                    annotation.imageView.file = image;
                    [annotation.imageView loadInBackground];

                    [self.theMap addAnnotation:annotation];

                    [self.theMap setCenterCoordinate:annotation.coordinate animated:YES];

                    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
                }
            }
        }];
    }];
```

Any help appreciated.
Marko

Comment: What's the exact problem or question?

Comment: How can I get the Image (loaded from Parse), to the annotation, like in the screenshot above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of this discussion: [Custom annotations with same image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292462/custom-annotations-with-same-image?rq=1)

I came out with this: [image: My Photo Map]

Here's the code:

```
MapViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>


@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property double latitude;
@property double longitude;


@end

MapViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    self.theMap.delegate = self;
    self.theMap.showsUserLocation = YES;

    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"HomePopulation"];
        [query whereKey:@"geopoint" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinKilometers:1000];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                     PFGeoPoint *thePoint = [object objectForKey:@"geopoint"];
                    latitude = thePoint.latitude;
                    longitude = thePoint.longitude;

                    NSLog(@" Hej %f, %f", latitude, longitude);
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

                    Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
                    annotation.coordinate = annotationCoordinate;
                    annotation.title = [object objectForKey:@"discovery"];
                    annotation.subtitle = [object objectForKey:@"location"];
                    annotation.objectID = object.objectId;

                    [self.theMap addAnnotation:annotation];
                }
            }
        }];
    }];

    //[self.theMap reloadInputViews];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"theLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]]) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.theMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        //annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-40, -100, 100, 100)];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        NSString *id = [(Annotation *)annotationView.annotation objectID];

        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"HomePopulation"];
        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", id] block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
            [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }];
        }];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pointer"];
        [annotationView addSubview:imageView];

        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}

Annotation.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *objectID;


@end
```

Comment: what is <parse/parse.h> i couldn't find in my framework as well as i could't import that file

Comment: would you like to give me sample code what you've done ...? means sample project of map with images.

Comment: Parse is the cloud service I use in this app. I suggest you take a look at this link: https://parse.com/products/ios#overview where you have all informations, step-by-step guides and documentations that you need.

Comment: Thanks A million Brother.. Its Very Helpful to me... and one thing Would You like to make a professional relationship ? would you like to give me your Facebook link if u don't mind.. Me too is fresher in iOS app development.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use Facebook. Write me a mail on devxhkl@outlook.com and let's see what we can do :)