# i want ios map api cluster like instagram photo map

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, markerclusterer

I have tried all the way to make like instagram photo map in ios app. Please tell me if you have any link or code to help.

I have tried google map library and as well custom clubbing but unfortunately not got success.

Comment: see this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444166/map-with-photos-like-instagram-photo-map

question already being asked